# SSRS Report Hiding columns from different clients

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am having a requirement,say like a report having 6 columns(1,2,3,4,5,6)
and I need to send this report to 2 clients A and B

client A needs only(1,2,3,4)

and Client B needs only(5,6)

How do I approach this ? I am very new to SSRS.

Comment: Please show your effort. We can help you with specific problems only.

Comment: I am very new to ssrs,I dont have any idea regarding this pls

Comment: Hint - Get the ClientID as parameter and depending on that value set the visibility of the columns you need to show/hide.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a parameter with the client id in it, like @Client, and @Client="A".
You can put an "iif" function in the hidden attribute of each column.
For example:
Colunm1.Hidden would be =iif(Parameters!Client.Value="A", False, True)

Is that what you are looking for?  Maybe enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following =IIF(Fields!MyID.Value > 0, True, False). Try returning "SomeFieldValue" as an integer either at the database or dataset level it can be the client id.

For instance in your dataset query, cast SomeFieldValue (client) to an int and then in the column visibility expression try:

```
=IIF(Fields!SomeFieldValue.Value > 0, True, False)
```